# Expressing a double sum using harmonic numbers

Tags: calculus, summation

The question asks to express the below double sum in terms of harmonic numbers.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{15} \sum_{k=15}^{30} \dfrac{1}{ki}$$

by harmonic number they just mean the formula being summed is 1 over $k$ where $k$ starts at 1 and can end at some number. so, if we denote a harmonic number as $H_n$ where $n$ is the number the sum stops at then $5H_2 + 28H_7$ would be an acceptable answer.

I'm only used to dealing with double sums by evaluating the inner sum first then doing the outer second. So I haven't made any progress trying to break this up without evaluating and rewriting it after

Comment: Have you tried swapping the order of the sums?

Comment: And then perhaps you should try setting the limits on $k$ to, say, $2$ and $5$, and the limits on $i$ from $1$ to $6$, so that you can write things out and try to notice a pattern. Hint: when you see $k \cdot i$, don't muiltiply. I mean: write $\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}$ rather than $\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: This is great!  May you also explain, or redirect me to, how I could prove that swapping the order of sums produces an equivalent expression?  I tried the case I posted with smaller limits and the equality holds but I'm not sure how to justify this. Also, does swapping the order always apply or is the case I posted a special case?  Thanks again

Comment: Swapping the order of the sums is allowed by applying the commutative and associative laws for addition multiple times; the usual proof of this is by induction. It applies, however, only to finite sums --- for infinite sums, it's not generally allowed. In the context of integrals, Fubini's theorem gives conditions under which swapping *is* allowed, and perhaps gives some insight about why in general it's not.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{15}\sum_{k=15}^{30}\frac{1}{ki}=\sum_{i=1}^{15}\left(\frac{1}{i}\sum_{k=15}^{30}\frac{1}{k}\right)=\left(\sum_{k=15}^{30}\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{15}\frac{1}{i}\right)=(H_{30}-H_{15})H_{15}$$